# Cannot read 'length' property for a defined object

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Angular component which contains a table with users, they are displayed correctly, but there is an ERROR when opening browser console:

```
compiler.js:18239 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
compiler.js:18239 ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 2, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

I have moved user loading to ngOnInit where I subscribe and save data in 'this.users' array,

```
  users: User[] = [];
  constructor(
    public userService: UserService
  ) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getAllUsers()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.users = data;
        }
      );
  }
```

The HTML component:

```
<nz-table [nzData]="users" [nzShowPagination]="false">
        <tr>
          <th>User</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let data of users">
          <td>{{ data.userName }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </nz-table>
```

Why I am getting undefined error when clearly the data is defined and visible in the list?

Comment: How do you initialize your `users` array in the component?

Comment: Try adding `<nz-table *ngIf="users" ....>`

Comment: When defining `users` array try to set default value `[]` to it

Comment: This is because your users object is undefined at the time of Component Initialization, and you assign data to it when data is present. To fix the issue, define users as an empty array. users = [];

Comment: did you write codes inside function or not?

Comment: ` this.userService.getAllUsers()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.users = data;
        }
      );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears in the first angular check cycles, when your data doesn't exist yet (your subscribed isn't finished) but your array was defined. It solves itself when the subscribe is finished.
If you want to get rid of the error simply add a `*ngIf="users"` to your `nz-table` markup